# How can I change some numbers in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I do not want to change all of them just some of them in particular rule.

For example the list is given `a={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9....,100}`

If the number is bigger than `5`, the number should be added `1`.

`a' = {*1,2,3,4,5*,**7,8,9,10,...,101**}`

I tried

```
 Replace[i,i-> i + 1]
```

or

```
For[i=6,i<102,i++]
```

but they didn't work. Please help me.

Comment: Try `ReplaceAll` together with `Condition` (short forms `/.` and `/;`) :  `a /. x_ /; x>5 :>x+1`.

Comment: @jjc385 That is sloppy because it will also attempt to transform the whole list, as well as its head.  It does work, but only because things like `List > 5` and `{1,2,3} > 5` do not evaluate to `True`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Point taken.  It's a shame that the `/.` syntax being so much more convenient than e.g. `//Replace[#, rule, 1]&` provides such a disincentive to do things the proper way.

Comment: @Szabolcs At times I even find myself wishing the `/.` (and `//.`) syntax sugar didn't exist, particularly when refactoring code from replacement over lists to replacement over associations (i.e., their values).

Comment: @Szabolcs I've turned these comments into an (answer)(https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144904/11035).  Considering I criticize an approach I myself suggested yesterday, I'm curious in which ways your perspective may differ.  (Apologies for all the pings.)

Comment: @jjc385 I don't have an issue with `ReplaceAll` in general.  I am often sloppy and use it in situations like this (though I prefer to avoid it in package code which needs to be robust).   I mentioned this here only because the OP is new to Mathematica.

Answer (score 7):

```
Replace[Range @ 100, i_ /; i > 5 -> i + 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 6):

Some ways (with acknowledgement Kuba):

```
UnitStep[a - 6] + a
a /. {x_?(# > 5 &) :> x + 1}

f[x_] := x + 1 /; x > 5
f[x_] := x
f /@ a

a + (Boole[# > 5] & /@ a)
```

Answer (score 6):

There are many solutions here, but I find none of them (except the one by @garej) particularly straightforward or beginner friendly.

> **If** the number is bigger than 5, the number should be added 1.

Use [`If`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html) then, and write a function which performs this transformation:

```
transformNumber[n_] := If[n > 5, n + 1, n]
```

Then test the function on individual inputs and make sure that it does what you want it to do:

```
transformNumber[4]
(* 4 *)

transformNumber[5]
(* 5 *)

transformNumber[6]
(* 7 *)
```

How do you transform each element in a list?  Use [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html):

```
transformNumber /@ a

transformNumber /@ Range[10]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11} *)
```

---

Looking at your use of `Replace` and `For`, it seems that you are guessing blindly, without any understanding of what these functions do.  Experimentation is useful when learning to program, but *blind* random guessing is not. I recommend you go through some [basic](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/) [tutorials](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/1847/) first, and look up any functions you are trying to use in the documentation: [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html), [`For`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/For.html).  But if you are a beginner, it is better to learn [`Do`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html) [before starting to use `For`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/12).

Comment: +1 for the advice on experimentation for beginners.

Answer (score 6):

[Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs) response to my comment inspired to me write an answer:

```
Replace[ a, x_ /; x>5 :> x+1, 1 ]
```

---

This is very similar to Garej's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144853/11035) : 
`Replace[Range @ 100, i_ /; i > 5 -> i + 1, 1]`
(**Uses `->` ([`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html)) rather than `:>` ([`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html))**)

It's also similar to my comment :
`a /. x_ /; x>5 :> x+1`
(**Uses `/.` ([`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html)) rather than [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html)**)

---

Why use `:>` ([`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html)) rather than `->` ([`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html))?

Consider this:

```
a=Range[10];    
x=-99;

ruleDelayedMethod   = Replace[ a, x_ /; x>5 :> x+1, 1 ]
```

> `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}`

```
ruleMethod          = Replace[ a, x_ /; x>5 -> x+1, 1 ]
```

> `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -98, -98, -98, -98, -98}`

The difference is that the `x` on the right hand side (RHS) of `:>` refers specifically to the `x` which matches the pattern `x_`.*  (We say that `x` is localized on the right hand side of `RuleDelayed` but not `Rule`.)  Mathematica's syntax highlighting nicely supports this:  Both `x`'s in `x_ :> x` are colored green, whereas the RHS of `x_->x` is colored black.

<sub>*In fact, `x_` precisely means "a pattern named `x` which matches `_`, (i.e., any expression)"</sub>

Moreover, the right hand side of `->` is evaluated immediately, whereas the right hand side of `:>` doesn't evaluate until the rule is actually applied (hence the name `RuleDelayed`).  You can real more about the difference between `Rule` and `RuleDelayed` on their respective documentation pages:  ([Docs for `Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html))([Docs for `RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html)).

**This was something which confused me as a new user.**  In fact, my first question on this site was a now-closed/deleted question about why `->` was failing, when I should have been using `:>`.

---

Why use 
[`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html)
rather than 
[`ReplaceAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) (`/.`) ?

`ReplaceAll` checks whether various pieces of the expression match the LHS of the rule.  `Replace` takes a 'level spec' argument which tells you which components of the expression to check.  As such,`ReplaceAll` is both more efficient and more portable.

To quote Szabolcs' [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144828/how-can-i-change-some-numbers-in-a-list?noredirect=1#comment389557_144828)

> [Using `ReplaceAll`] is sloppy because it will also attempt to
>   transform the whole list, as well as its head. It does work, but only
>   because things like `List > 5` and `{1,2,3} > 5` do not evaluate to
>   True.

As humans, users may favor the simple syntax sugar of `/.` over typing out `Replace[ ... , 1]`, as I did in my original comment.  One may ask whether there's a nice solution to this.  One option use a pure function as a postfix operator:

```
a // Replace[ #, x_ /; x>5 :> x+1, 1 ]&
```

Another option is to use [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) (`/@`), taking advantage of the operator form of `Replace` :

```
Replace[ x_ /; x>5 :> x+1 ] /@ a
```

or (equivalently)

```
a // Map@Replace[ x_ /; x>5 :> x+1 ]
```

Note that the two potential solutions using `Map` (`/@`) are particularly simple because the replacement occurs at level 1 in the list.  Were a deeper level required, the solution using `Map` becomes less elegant than simply supplying `Replace` with a levelspec as the third argument.

One solution which (1) has a similar look and feel to using the `/.` syntactic sugar and (2) scales nicely when a levelspec is required is to define a custom operator form for `Replace` which takes a levelspec:

```
ClearAll[replaceLev]

replaceLev[ rule_, levelspec_ ][ expr_ ] := 
 Replace[ expr, rule, levelspec ]
```

Then one can solve the original post's problem with:

```
a // replaceLev[ x_ /; x>5 :> x+1, 1 ]
```

Comment: @tomd I'd say your comment, while technically correct, is a bit misleading.  [`ReplacePart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html) works **completely differently** from `Replace` and friends.  In particular, the rule supplied to `ReplacePart` is applied to the *index* of each subpart rather than that subpart's value.  Example:  `ReplacePart[{97, 98, 99}, x_ :> x]` returns `{1,2,3}`.

Comment: You are of course absolutely correct.  I have deleted the comment.  I was aware of this (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4571427/499167)) but I do not use Mma much these days (limited access), unfortunately. (`ReplacePart[#, 3 -> 10 #[[3]]] & /@ ConstantArray[20, {3, 3}]`, for example)

Answer (score 4):

also

```
a = Range[10];
MapAt[# + 1 &, a, Position[a, _?(# > 5 &), 2]];
(* or MapAt[# + 1 &, a, Position[a, x_ /; x > 5, 2]] *)
a
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

Answer (score 4):

```
a=Range@10;
Join[Select[a, # <= 5 &], Select[a, # > 5 &] + 1]
(*{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(#[[;; #2]]~Join~Cases[#, x_ /; x > #2 :> x + 1]) &[Range@100, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since V 11.2 there is `TakeList`

```
a = Range[10];

Flatten[TakeList[a, {5, 5}] + {0, 1}]
```

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}

Or with `ReplaceAt` (since V 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[a, x_ :> x + 1, {5 ;;}]
```

{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}

Answer (score 2):

Some more.

With

```
a = Range[10]
```

we can use the command [`Clip`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip.html) as follows:

```
Clip[#, {-Infinity, 5}, {0, # + 1}] & /@ a
```

another way using [`ReplacePart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html)

```
ReplacePart[#, Position[#, x_ /; x > 5] -> # + 1] & /@ a
```

and [`UnitStep`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep.html)

```
a + (1 - UnitStep[5 - a])
```

All of the above give

> `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11}`

Answer (score 1):

Using `Compile` and `Table`:

```
f = Compile[{{x, _Integer}}, Table[If[i <= 5, i, i + 1], {i, x}]]
```

Test:

```
f@100 // RepeatedTiming
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) from me. Nicely done mate!

Comment: Thanks, mate! It's good to greet you again.